# Installing multiple versions of python3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to use Python3.7 on my system, but I have Python3.5 installed. For backwards compatibility, I'd like to keep the latter installed while also using the former for new programs. But I'm afraid I'll break things.

Is this possible in the first place? If yes, will I break things? Do the commands `python3.5 -V` and `python3.7 -V` still give the right versions? Will it still be possible to use `virtualenv -p python3.x venv` for either version?

Comment: This one worked for me without breaking things.
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's better answered by the askubuntu site! try the following: https://askubuntu.com/a/101634 (just use `python3.7` obviously)